# Nested Operations in Handlebars

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to use nested operation in Handlerbars like

```
if(value == "a" || value == "b")
```

How can I create this equations using handlebar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create helper (I use `underscore.js` for simplicify):

**eq.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eq', function() {
  var i, options, val1, vals;
  val1 = arguments[0], vals = 3 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 1, i = arguments.length - 1) : (i = 1, []), options = arguments[i++];
  return _.any(vals, function(val) {
    return val1 === val;
  });
});
```

or **eq.coffee**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'eq', (val1, vals..., options) -> _.any vals, (val) -> val1 is val
```

And use:

```
{{eq value 'a' 'b'}}
```